# eZPublish fetching content with php

Tags: php, fetch, ezpublish

I'm trying to fetch content using php. But my code seems not to work. I'm using `ezcontentobjecttreenode::subtree` function but it displays this error:

```
Using $this when not in object context in /home/quejadore/site/kernel/classes/ezcontentobjecttreenode.php on line 2032
```

Here is my code.

```
$params = $nodes =& eZContentObjectTreeNode::subTree( array( 
    'Depth' => 3,
    'SortBy' => array( 'published', false),
    'Limit' => 3,
    'ClassFilterType' => 'include',
    'ClassFilterArray' => array('article_v3'),
    'Attribute_filter' => array(array('article_v3/on_newsletter', '=',true))));

$nodes =& eZContentObjectTreeNode::subTree( $params, 21312);
```

Anyone can help please? Thanx in advance

I have now edited my code(even if it still not working yet).Here is what i have now:

```
$params = array('Depth' => 3,
            'Limit' =>1,
            'IgnoreVisibility' => true,
            'Limitation' => array(),
            'ClassFilterType' => 'include',
            'ClassFilterArray' => array('article_v3'),
            'AttributeFilter' => array(array('article_v3/on_newsletter','=',true)));


$obj = new eZContentObjectTreeNode;
$nodes = $obj->subTree($params, 21312);
$dataMap =$nodes->attribute( 'data_map' );
$image =& $dataMap['image']->content();
$list =& $image->aliasList();
var_dump( $list['original']['url'] );
```

Comment: You're calling a method statically, and it's NOT a static method... you need to instantiate an eztree object and call the method properly `$foo = new EzWhatever; $foo->subtree(...)`

Comment: THanx for that quick answer Marc. It seems to work.but my array is NULL. And i'm sure that the params meet at least 50 objects :|

Comment: Try `AttributeFilter`, not `Attribute_filter`

Comment: It looks like to be the good parameter but it still NULL.

Answer (score 1):

So i found the solution.Here's my code :

```
$params = array(
            'Depth' => 3,
            'AsObject' => true,
            'Limit' =>3,
            'SortBy' => array( 'published', false),
            'IgnoreVisibility' => true,
            'Limitation' => array(),
            'ClassFilterType' => 'include',
            'ClassFilterArray' => array('article_v3'),
            'AttributeFilter' => array(array('article_v3/on_newsletter', '=', true)));

$nodes = eZContentObjectTreeNode::subTreeByNodeID($params, 21312);
```

Thanx to all

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how to use fetch functions in PHP, have a look at the template fetch functions reference, in your case : https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Modules/content/Fetch-functions/tree

Replace parameters by their 'classified' version : `attribute_filter` becomes `AttributeFilter`, `class_filter_type` becomes `ClassFilterArray`, etc... Remember that eZ Publish takes care of the visibility and role permissions, even if you are using the PHP API. If you want to ignore this, use `'IgnoreVisibility' => true` in your parameters array.

Also, I'm not sure of what you are trying to do but you don't need to call this method by reference using `&`